# Matching factor levels from seperate data frames based on dates

Tags: r, date, match

I'm sure there is an easy solution to this (I can't seem to find a cut.date solution that works). I have one dataframe whereby monthly values have been classified into discrete categories.

```
Monthly <-as.data.frame(seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), as.Date("2016/12/31"), "months"))
colnames(Monthly) [1] <- "Date"
Monthly$Category <- c(rep("A", times = 7), rep("B", times = 12),
rep("C", times = 12),rep("B", times = 12), rep("C", times = 12),
 rep("B", times = 12),rep("C", times = 12), rep("A", times = 5))
```

I have a separate dataframe with a measured value and the day of a sample (taken within the same time frame as the monthly values, but lots of samples were collected on the same day).

```
Daily <- as.data.frame(c(rep(as.Date("2010/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2010/08/24"), times = 200), rep(as.Date("2011/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2011/08/24"), times = 200),rep(as.Date("2012/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2012/08/24"), times = 200),rep(as.Date("2013/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2013/08/24"), times = 200),rep(as.Date("2014/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2014/08/24"), times = 200),rep(as.Date("2015/03/12"), times = 200),
rep(as.Date("2015/08/24"), times = 200),rep(as.Date("2016/03/12"), times = 157)))

Values <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:200,255.7*10, replace=TRUE),ncol=1))
df <- data.frame(Values,Daily)
colnames(df) <- c("values","daily")
```

I want to create a new column in df containing the category of the corresponding month. So for example, based on the 'Monthly' dataframe, March 2010 could be classified in category A. So in the new column of df, I would like all samples taken in March 2010 to have an 'A' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution using `merge`:

```
out<-merge(df,Monthly,by.x=substr(as.character("daily"),1,7),by.y=substr(as.character("Date"),1,7))
```

Your output:

```
head(out,10)
        daily values Category
1  2010-01-01     29        A
2  2010-02-01    132        A
3  2010-03-01     60        A
4  2010-04-01     96        A
5  2010-05-01     69        A
6  2010-06-01     18        A
7  2010-07-01     47        A
8  2010-08-01    133        B
9  2010-09-01    121        B
10 2010-10-01     73        B
```

**In a different way**

Key creation between dataframes

```
df$id<-substr(as.character(df$daily),1,7)
Monthly$id<-substr(as.character(Monthly$Date),1,7)
```

Join using `id`

```
library(plyr)
out<-join(df, Monthly, by="id",type="full")
```

Your output

```
head(out[,c(2,1,5)])
daily values Category
1 2010-03-12     94        A
2 2010-03-12     73        A
3 2010-03-12    132        A
4 2010-03-12     94        A
5 2010-03-12    164        A
6 2010-03-12     81        A
```

Comment: This is great thanks but it doesn't seem to work on my data, I think perhaps because I have multiple repeated dates in 'daily' (lots of samples were taken on the same day). I will edit to try and make this more clear sorry

Comment: Try adding all.y=TRUE in the merge function

Comment: Using the new example and all.y = TRUE, all of the values appear as NAs. With my own data, I am getting the error 'fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column' - any clue as to what is causing this? Thank you for your help/

Comment: Try the other way posted.

Comment: Perfect thank you! It appends NA rows at the bottom for some reason, but a simple 'complete.cases' sorts this and no data is lost :)